# Look for a value in a DataTable column

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable dt that have a Column month it looks like this.

```
month
yes
yes
```

I want to check if the column month contains "yes". I don't have a primary key in the Datatable dt.
Something like this

```
if( dt.["month"] == "yes")
 boolMonth = true;
```

Comment: You wanna check _any_ row of that column has `yes`? What is the type of this `month` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assumed, you want to check if any row equals the string value "yes":

```
if(dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Any( x => (string)x["month"] == "yes"))
boolMonth = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use [LINQ to DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx) like (assume `month` type is `string`);

```
bool boolMonth  = dt.AsEnumerable().
                     Any(row => row.Field<string>("month") == "yes");
```